# Microsoft Visual C++ Target O/S

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am working on a .NET application that is using C++ libraries. One library is a C++/CLR library that uses another C++ library. The application that uses these libraries is required to operate at least on Windows 7. The system is compiled using Visual Studio 2019, and is using the latest SDK. From what I've read, using the latest SDK is possible if targeting at minimum Windows 7.

When I launch the application on Windows 7, I get the following error:

> A procedure imported by 'XXX.Net.dll' could not be loaded.

Running on Windows 10 causes no problems.

`XXX.Net.dll` is the C++/CLR library which uses the C++ library.

I read that setting the `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT` macros would explicitly target the version that is wanted. I've added these definitions based on what Microsoft indicated:

> to modify the macros, in a header file (for example, in targetver.h

So, within my C++ library, I added the following macro declaration to `targetver.h`:

```
#define WINVER 0x0601
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
```

From what I understand, this should allow the library to operate properly on Windows 7. Can someone tell me why this would not work?

Note: we are using Ninject for packing all binaries into the main binary. And this error occurs in the line:

```
new StandardKernel(new Bindings().
```

Comment: Has the appropriate .NET been installed on the Windows 7 machine?

Comment: Did you modify targetver.h that was already being included, or did you create a new file?  If a new file, did you arrange for it to be included before all windows headers (especially windows.h) ?

Comment: Which procedures from other DLLs does `XXX.Net.dll` actually import? Did you try looking for those DLLs and see what they are actually exporting so you can find what is missing?

Comment: To support a range of operating systems, it's a really good idea to have virtual machines set up for each in your development environment.  If you run Visual Studio on Windows 7 and debug the application, what do you get?

Comment: yes - correct .NET version is installed on the O/S

Comment: I added the #include "targetver.h" file -- it is setup in the following way:

#include <WinSDKVer.h>
#define WINVER 0x0601
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>

it is included in my pre compiled header - comes after another include  that has the following 

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files
#include <windows.h>

-- if I put "targetver.h" before this include I compile errors

Comment: the other DLL is one we put together - and all the operations are being used

Comment: running on Windows 7 -- which is how we identified the problem am getting the following error

System.IO.FileLoadException: 'A procedure imported by 'ServiceHide.Net.dll' could not be loaded.'

Comment: the underlying target .NET is 4 -- am trying to get the C++ library to work on Windows 7 - using VS 2019 - using latest SDK - from MS documentation this is suppose to be allowed - but indicate the MACROS I identified in original posting are to be used - which seems to not work

Answer (score -1):

OK -- I had decided to test the library failing directly -- and found that the library was accessing an SDK operation not available on Windows 7 - which was causing the library to fail.